# I can't seem to get shadows to work in my Three.js scene

Tags: three.js, shadow, gltf

I want to get shadows in my scene but the shadow doesn't show up or is glitched/not right.

I've tried to get it to work with AmbientLight, PointLight, DirectionalLight but none of them seem to work.

I've set the lights to cast shadows and set all the meshes in the scene to cast and receive shadows.

My renderer

```
var renderer,
        scene,
        camera;

    //RENDERER
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap; 

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

The light

```
    //LIGHTS
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    directionalLight.position.set( 150, 50, 100 );


    var d = 5;
    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - d;
    directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
    directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
    directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - d;    

    directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
    directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 20;
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    light2.position.set(0,50,50);
    light2.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(light2);
```

How I load my objects and set them to cast and receive shadows

```
    //LOAD OBJECTS
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    loader.load('landingpagev2.glb', handle_load);

    var mesh;

    function handle_load(gltf) {

        mesh = gltf.scene;
        for(var i = 0; i < mesh.children.length; i++){
            mesh.children[i].material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
            mesh.children[i].castShadow=true;
            mesh.children[i].receiveShadow=true;
        }
        scene.add( mesh );
        mesh.position.set(4,2.3,-10);
        mesh.rotation.set(-80,0,0);
    }
```

The shadows keep showing glitched-like or don't show at all when working with different lights.
The whole code is online at [ramonhoffman.nl/three](https://www.ramonhoffman.nl/three) so you can see what I'm working with.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You might want to check near/far and map size handling. You only see pixels of your shadows at this time. If you add some interactive elements to try out light and camera settings you might get a better grip on what setting will give you a proper shadow.